# How to use custom font in visual studio 2008 for C#.net window application?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I want to use Indian Font (Hindi) in Windows apps.When i used Mangal font for Hindi text ,then text visible but in block format.

so any one can help me for this.

[image]

Comment: Do you definitely have the font installed on your system? Do any characters from the font display correctly in your WinForms application?

Comment: yess i have already installed that font in my system

Comment: You get rectangles when the font doesn't have the glyph for the character you are trying to display.  Use the Charmap.exe applet to see what Unicode codepoints are valid for the font.

Comment: @user : how can i type kannada fonts in my windows forms, pleas help me

Answer (score 1):

Create New windows forms project and in Form.OnLoad handler, add the following lines:

```
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
string fontFilePath = "C:\\Fonts\\PALETX3.ttf"
pfc.AddFontFile(fontFilePath);
label1.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 16, FontStyle.Regular);
```

You can find more information from 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533820(VS.85).aspx

Comment: You need to change the line
   label1.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 16, FontStyle.Regular);
to match your TextBox

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
YourMainForm.YourTextBox.Font = new Font("Your name of indian font", 
                                         YourMainForm.YourTextBox.Font.Size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the font you are using supports the Unicode characters in controls. You can find this out using windows utility *Character Map*.

Some older fonts have characters for a certain code page but not for Unicode characters. For example windows font *Marlett* have only a few Unicode chars defined, the rest will appear as the boxes in your screen shot. If that is the case your best bet is to find a newer Unicode version of the font. Although in theory you can use font editing software to create a new version yourself (the glyphs are already in there) but it won't be easy. Best of luck :)